# How to retrieve version item files in TFS

Tags: tfs, version

Dears
We are using TFS2013 server to create and track requirements. Some work items are linked to some files on the version control as in the figure below:

[image: screenshot]

I am looking for C# code to retrieve the path of these files on server. Anyone can help? 
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve linked "versioned item" from TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993147/how-to-retrieve-linked-versioned-item-from-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

Same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15010657/675826

From the Workitem, you need to query links of the type ExternalLink.
These external links map to an artifact which contain the metadata (like file version and source path).